# Вызов метода объекта из другого метода в коде callback'a для jquery селектора

Tags: javascript, jquery

возможно ли и как такое реализовать?

```
var obj = (function ($) {
    return {
        func1: function () {
                console.log("do something");
        },
        func2: function () {
                // do something
             $("#debug").click(function () {
                // do something
                func1();
                // do something
             })
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

obj.func2(); // по клику на #debug получаем - Uncaught ReferenceError: func1 is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С минимальными изменениями в вашем коде вот:

```
var obj = (function ($) {
        return {
            func1: function() {
                    console.log("do something");
            },
            func2: function () {
                 $("#debug").click(function () {
                    this.func1(); //2. обращаемся к нужному контексту
                 }.bind(this)) //1. привязываем контекст
            }
        }
    })(jQuery);

    obj.func2();
```

Смысл следующий
1). Передаем обработчику контекст объекта. Можно это сделать не через bind если вы не хотите подменять весь контекст обработчика, а например через сохранение  в локальной переменной в духе `var me = this`
2). Собственно у нас есть контекст, в нем есть функция, осталось ее вызвать.

Да, добавлю что лучше бы определить функции которые вы возвращаете до return, это будет намного понятнее. Но это уже стилистический вопрос